# How to handle missing categorical data in data analysis using pandas when dataset contains more than 50000 missing values?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a situation where I need to fill the missing in the categorical variables. The dataset has 50000 missing.

I tried with `fillna(data[].value_counts().index[0],inplace=True)`
Is it ok or is there any loss in data?